# Adobe Illustrator scripting export JSX

Tags: scripting, extendscript

I am trying to loop over 2 different top layers on my .ai file, each top layer contains several sub layers. The 2 top layers are icons (usual ui stuff) and modifiers (like plus and minus symbols).

I want to loop over all of the icons layers and for each one apply every modifier to it. So in total I want to end up with all icons exported with every modifier on each of them.

Currently I have been looking at examples but they only consist of exporting the top layer only and not sub-layers.

Comment: This is probably considered more of a graphics question, I have also asked it there - http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53955/adobe-illustrator-script-to-walk-through-layers-while-exporting -
But it has scripting that needs to be done and any skeleton of some code would benefit me very much.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware it can be done in case every your icon is a group with a non-arbitrary name (for example: *icon01*, *icon02*, etc). And every modifer is a group with a name which can be associated with a name of its icon (for example: *icon01plus*, *icon01minus*, etc). After that you can iterate through all groups by its names and save them. You don't even need layers and sublayers.

If you wish to use layers, you need to do about the same work first. You should place every your icon and every its modifer on a separate layers with a proper name. Then iterate through all the objects and select them by its layer.

If all your icons has the same size and the modifers has the same size/position there can be more efficient implementations as well.